# Visual Studio said my variables are useless in a private method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I have simple scenario where I started to repeat same code multiple times, so I decided to move it in a private method, depending on a if/else it's being edited and my variables that are listed below might overwrite it's value which is perfectly fine:

```
ProductResponse identificationResults = new ProductResponse(); // I understand this assignment gets overridden in private method below but that is goal
long? productIdentificationRecordId = null; // I understand this assignment gets overridden in private method below but that is goal
```

I'm invoking my method on a few places in a code that's reason why I created private method to avoid code repetition in same file:

```
await SetProductStatusAndPerformDbActions(productCompany, userId );


private async Task SetProductStatusAndPerformDbActions(Company productCompany, long userId, ProductType productType, ProductStatus status, long? productIdentificationRecordId, ProductResponse identificationResults, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    status = GetCompanyProductStatus(productCompany.Id, identificationResults);

    productIdentificationRecordId = await PerformDbAction(status, productType, userId, cancellationToken); // underlined this code

    identificationResults = await IdentifyCompanyProduct(productCompany, cancellationToken); // underlined this code
}
```

> Visual Studio says 'Remove this useless assignment to a local variable
> productIdentificationRecordId'
>
> Visual Studio says 'Remove this useless assignment to a local variable
> identificationResults'

I understand this assignments gets overridden in private method below but that is point of private method because I want to use for example `productIdentificationRecordId` and its new value right after I call this private method because goal of private method is to modify it and that is it..

I'm not using vars which might cause this warning so I don't know what to do here.

How this could be written to avoid this scenarios ?

Edit:

Added screenshot from the private method, variables are grayed as they are not used:

[image]

Comment: Can you try to boil it down to a [mcve]? I'm worried that there might be hidden nuances we can't see here.

Comment: Can you pinpoint which assignment Visual Studio is saying is unnecessary?

Comment: Is Visual Studio kicking the error on the first assignments outside of the method or the assignments inside the method?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It is related to those 2 variables in private method `productIdentificationRecordId`   & `identificationResults` . Read comments below code sample. I will add a screenshot in a minut so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. The variables in question are the **parameters** to the methods. You've hidden any same-named fields with those parameters. The value of the parameters are never used later, so assigning anything to them is in fact useless. Why did you include those parameters at all? Did you mean for them to be passed by-reference? I.e. with `out`? Do you really need those parameters at all? Could you omit them and achieve what you want? Please fix your question so that it's more clear.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes they are passed by reference, this method is basically used to modify them since those parameters that are being modified are used just after private method call.. I will update my question a bit so you could see how it's invoked / used in a rest of a code. Thanks mate

Comment: I think it's a safe guess based on your additional comments that those parameters should be declared as out parameters, so the method signature should be:
`private async Task SetProductStatusAndPerformDbActions(Company productCompany, long userId, ProductType productType, ProductStatus status, out long? productIdentificationRecordId, out ProductResponse identificationResults, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

Comment: _"they are passed by reference"_ -- not in the code you posted here, they're not.

Comment: @SergeyK Async method can not have ref in out parameters o,0

Comment: @RoxyPro What do you do with productIdentificationRecordId? Where do you use it?  For what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because these parameters are not being passed by reference, setting them to any value will only change the value of the parameter variables local to your helper method: it will not impact the values that were passed in to those parameters.

Since you don't *use* the new values you're assigning to those parameters inside the method, Visual Studio is smart enough to recognize that setting values to them has no effect. It's warning you about that, which is good because in this case you might think your code is doing something that it's not really doing.

Comment: Definately explained nice. And what is solution here to make effect by settings values to passed variables ? Thanks Warrior

Comment: The best pattern is usually to make the helper method return a value with the values you expect to have "output", and only use the parameters you pass in as "input". So you'd change your method from returning a `Task` to returning a `Task<...>` where the `...` could be a tuple, class, or record containing the status, productIdentificationRecordId, and identificationResults.

Comment: (and obviously don't pass those values in as parameters)